# The Jenkins "trigger build" Service on bitbucket doesn't trigger the build

Tags: git, service, jenkins, push, bitbucket

I followed this tutorial:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Jenkins+Service+Management
And I think I did everything I have to do in Jenkins in order to get the build started remotely. But when pushing to the repo it doesn't trigger the build. 
Jenkins is run on our server so I checked the logs and found the POST request from the bitbucket service. When I paste the URL in my Browser and make a GET request, it works...

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong?

Comment: Does really no one have any hint for me? :/

Comment: I also deactivate the "Cross Site Request Forgery" option

Comment: The link you posted is a dead link now. Did you get it working in the end? There's some documentation here https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Jenkins+hook+management

Comment: Look at answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31202359/bitbucket-jenkins-doesnt-automatically-build/36319282#36319282.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue with the **BitBucket POST hook** and having Jenkins' "Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits" checked under the **Manage Jenkins => Configure Global Security Settings**.

Turning that off allows the POSTs to be recognized.

You can use the Jenkins Hook in BitBucket if you need csrf support, but you then lose the flexibility of a custom POST hook.