# BitBucket Jenkins doesn't automatically build

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

On my Jenkins I configured:

**Source Code Management**

Git repository: https://bitbucket.org/username/project.git

credentials: username/password

**Builder Triggers**

Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket

On my BitBucket Webhooks:

http://Jenkins.URL:8080/bitbucket-hook

I tried pushing a small change to a .txt file, but the Jenken doesn't build automatically. If I manually click "build now", it shows success.

What could be the problem?

In the bitbucket repository, the project is simple. I just have a text file to test. I think as long as I made any change to the text file, it should trigger a Jenkins build.

Edit:

In the System Log of Jenkins, it shows "Polling has not run yet.". But in Bitbucket Webhook request log, I can see all the requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Adrian mentioned, you still need to select "Poll SCM".  It's a little unintuitive, but when the BitBucket webhook sends a request to Jenkins, Jenkins will poll for changes on all jobs that reference the BitBucket repo where the change was made.  You can set a long time interval for the poll, e.g. @monthly, as you don't need Jenkins' scheduling to trigger polling; the web hook will take care of that as soon as a change is made.

Comment: It seems working! I set 1 minute. Jenkins will build every minute, or whenever there is a change made to the repository

Comment: Doesn't this just poll every minute anyway then? What's the point of the bitbucket push trigger?

Comment: As @AlastairBrayne mentioned, the webhook is there to avoid repository polling. If you don't specify the schedule, Jenkins says `No schedules so will only run due to SCM changes if triggered by a post-commit hook`. SCM enabled or not, build is not triggered for me (Jenkins ver. 2.148)

Comment: You can enable logs to make sure your Jenkins receives data from BitBucket: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203819054-Bitbucket-plugin-does-not-trigger-builds

Comment: It was working for me without Poll SCM checked, then stopped this February.  It no longer works with or without it checked, unless I set a time, in which case the push trigger is meaningless.

Answer (score 54):

You don't need to enable Polling SCM..

You have to ensure that your Webhook (Settings->Webhooks) is pointing to your Jenkins `bitbucket-hook` like the following: "https://ci.yourorg.com/bitbucket-hook/".

**Notice that last "/", without it, the build will not be triggered.**

It's an annoying thing, as you will get a 200 status code from Jenkins when sending requests, with or without it.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, details like this are easy to overlook.

Comment: +1 for the missing "/" - this tripped me up and spent hours trying all the different methods. I can also confirm you DON'T need the Poll SCM option.

Comment: I would love to get this working without the Poll SCM option, but when I tried @Haukur's suggestion, I got a 404 error back. Is there something on the Jenkins side that needs to be enabled other than the Bitbucket plugin? It does work for me when I set the Poll SCM option in combination with "Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket". Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, this is the correct answer - and can't stress the "/" too much!

Comment: Does not work for me on Jenkins version 2.148 even with `/` at the end ):

Comment: My webhooks get a 200 status code but when I make a change on my branch jekins doesn't fire.

Comment: Link is broken 404

Comment: Literally `/bitbucket-hook/`?  Which plugin creates this Jenkins endpoint?

Comment: It should be noted that there are multiple Bitbucket plugins for Jenkins. Unfortunately, the question does not specify which plugin it refers to, but it's obviously about Bitbucket Cloud. For Bitbucket Server/DC and Atlassian's [Bitbucket Server Integration plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/atlassian-bitbucket-server-integration), I eventually found out that I had to configure the URL with path `/bitbucket-server-webhook/trigger` in the webhook.

Answer (score 17):

After some struggling with the BitBucket plugin, I have managed to get it working.
Below is the summary of things I found are necessary for builds to be triggered, but are not obvious from plugin's documentation:

1. Make sure your webhook has `repository push` trigger enabled. I thought `pull request created` / `updated` would suffice (building on PR is what I wanted) but [the plugin reacts only to `push`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/bitbucket-plugin/blob/ce068b7f2cbf5250aa6d54c3acdd455d45b56246/src/main/java/com/cloudbees/jenkins/plugins/BitbucketPayloadProcessor.java#L26).
2. Set your repository URL (in Git plugin) to `https://bitbucket.org/REPOSITORY_OWNER/REPOSITORY_NAME`. Plugin will not match it if it's the SSH url.
3. You **do** need the SCM polling enabled. The plugin itself does not pull the changes. You can leave the schedule field empty, so repository is polled only when the plugin triggers it.

I hope this helps. If the build is still not triggered for you, try [enabling logs](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203819054-Bitbucket-plugin-does-not-trigger-builds) for the following classes:

- `com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.BitbucketHookReceiver`
- `com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.BitBucketTrigger`
- `com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.BitbucketJobProbe`
- `com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.BitbucketPayloadProcessor`
- `com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.BitbucketSCMSource`

Comment: From my experience SCM polling is not needed, but you've got to do the first build manually.

Comment: All three are needed. Thanks! You saved me @Jezor

Answer (score 4):

Using Jenkins 2.53 and Bitbucket plugin 1.1.5, I had to manually trigger the build first to get the webhook to work.

What tipped me off was this line from the [documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BitBucket+Plugin):

> If the job's SCM (git) detects that the remote repository has changes, THEN

After that the webhook work great.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this issue and resolved by updating the bitbucket plugin in jenkins:

[image]

Also ensure that webhook url is in the correct format and has the '/' at the end:

**{JenkinsURL}/bitbucket-hook/**

Answer (score 1):

Did you mark the checkbox where it says: Poll SCM? Also make sure that you schedule a short time to detect the changes in the repository as soon as possible.

Maybe your problem is that you schedule for a long time and after your push Jenkins wait some time to detect the changes.

Comment: I selected "Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket", not Poll SCM.

Comment: Yes, I meant that you should select both. But as I see you already did it and it's working ;)

Comment: I'm struggling with this myself. (Got Poll SCM turned on and it still doesn't work.) But in regards this answer, surely if I turn on frequent scm polling then the build script will run that regularly anyway. In which case, what's the point of the bitbucket push trigger?

Comment: @Alistair you're right, you don't need to specify a frequent polling interval - in fact you don't have to enter a value at all, just make sure the Poll SCM box is checked.

Comment: It was working for me without Poll SCM checked, then stopped this February.  It no longer works with or without it checked, unless I set a time, in which case the push trigger is meaningless.

Comment: Turns out we had implemented StackPath which was blocking it.

Answer (score 1):

You must pay attention to the 
Branch specifier field and specify the branch that **you are pushing to**.

Jenkins plugin for Bitbucket will not start a job if no changes are detected.
you can add more than one branch to be watched.

as mentioned by the official documentation only If the job's SCM (git) detects that the remote repository has changes THEN it will invoke the build.

So if you leave the branch specifier with its default value */master and you are pushing to a different branch then the job will not be executed.

Answer (score 1):

For someone like me who is new to `jenkins` and `CI\CD`:

---

We should add `webhook`s individually for each repository we want to build automatically.

I was trying to build **a project** and i added `jenkins url` as `webhook` to **another project** and mistakenly thought that the `webhook` is universal for all projects under a bitbucket account. But which is not. Good little thing that can be easily overlooked sometimes.

Also, i used option: `Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket` not `Poll SCM` , other answers suggested that we should use that, but `Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket` option worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the same but without the [Bitbucket Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BitBucket+Plugin) in my Jenkins.

I'm using the [Jenkins Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.nerdwin15.stash-stash-webhook-jenkins/server/overview) in my Bitbucket. I've configured the webhook on each repository and pointing with the simply Jenkins URL.
Then, into every job that I need, just leave checked the "Poll SCM" with/without schedule (is not required).

With that is working really well and I avoid another plugin installation in my Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your projects page on https://bitbucket.org
2. Settings -> Webhook -> Click on "Add webhook"
3. Add https://yourjenkinsserver.com/bitbucket-hook/
4. Push again

This needs your Jenkisserver to have [the bitbucket plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/bitbucket). Check it by going to https://yourjenkinsserver.com/bitbucket-hook/ - it will crash, but you will know you installed it.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on Jenkins 2.138.1 with Bitbucket plugin and the problem was that I had to enable "Source Code Management" -> git, otherwise it won't do anything although the webhook appeared on Jenkins's log (/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log).

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this issue for long, and couldn't find a solution in Jenkins documentation, I found [here](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000051132-How-to-Trigger-Multibranch-Jobs-from-Bitbucket-Cloud-#furtherconfiguration) a solution in Cloudbees support site.

You just need to add these tow webhooks to your bitbucket repo :

```
https://JENKIN_URL/bitbucket-scmsource-hook/notify
https://JENKIN_URL/bitbucket-hook
```

And i work for all pipelines even MultiBranch ones.

Hope this helps someone ;)

ADA

Comment: this is old ref from 2017

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was solved by setting the Branch Options (Advanced Configuration) of the Bitbucket to Jenkins Webhook to "Build All".

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use a webhook inside Bitbucket Cloud and you are trying to trigger a build in Jenkins hosted in AWS EC2 you should add the outgoing IP addresses from Bitbucket to your security group. https://support.atlassian.com/organization-administration/docs/ip-addresses-and-domains-for-atlassian-cloud-products/

Answer (score -1):

I second the statements here that say we do not need POLL SCM option with "Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket" but we need to make sure that webhook created in Bit bucket is correct.

Settings I used in BitBucket are:
Repository Settings -> Webhooks

```
 1. Title: <Anything>
 2. URL: https://jenkins_server_ip:8443/bitbucket-hook/
 3. Status: (Tick) Active
 4. SSL / TLS: (Tick) Skip certificate verification (Not ticking this was causing no auto-trigger in my case)
 5. Request History: (Untick) Enable request history collection
 6. Triggers : (Tick) Repository push
```

Hope this helps!